# python-how to pass dictionaries as inputs in function without repeating the elements in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, packing

How I can pass the dictionaries as an input of a function without repeating the elements in function?

please see a simplified example below:

```
def myfuction(a,b,c):
    aa = b/2
    y = a+b+c+aa 
    return y

dict_1 = {'a':1,'b':2}
dict_2 = {'c':3}

myfuction(**dict_1, **dict_2)
```

The problem is that each dict in my code has 10 elements,

So either I should forget about dictionaries and write all values insides the function 
or use dicts and add 20 params in myfunction(inputs)

What is the best way to unpack parameters without repeating them.

Comment: That is wrong python code in the function. Can you please post a working code without syntax errors?

Comment: `...aa=kwargs['b']/2...` - https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I editted the question

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking - your edited example works for me.

Comment: The problem is that each dict in my code has 10 elements, 

So either I should forget about dictionaries and write all values insides in the function 
or use dicts and add 20 params in myfunction(inputs)

What is the best way to unpack parameters without repeating them.

Comment: Can you show us an example where you are repeating? What exactly do you mean by repeating?

Answer (score 2):

```py
def myfuction(a=0,b=0,c=0):
    aa = b/2
    y = a+b+c+aa 
    return y

dict_1 = {'a':1,'b':2}
dict_2 = {'c':3}

print(myfuction(**dict_1, **dict_2))
# 7
```

Answer (score 1):

`...the best way...` is going to be subjective....

Use `kwargs`:

```
def myfuction(**kwargs):
    aa = kwargs['b']/2
    y = kwargs['a'] + kwargs['b'] + kwargs['c'] + aa 
    return y
```

Using a namedtuple

```
import collections
def myfuction(**kwargs):
    D = collections.namedtuple('D',field_names=kwargs.keys(),defaults=kwargs.values())
    d = D()
    aa = d.b/2
    y = d.a + d.b + d.c + aa 
    return y
```

Using function attributes

```
def myfuction(**kwargs):
    for k,v in kwargs.items():
        setattr(myfuction,k,v)
    aa = myfuction.b/2
    y = myfuction.a + myfuction.b + myfuction.c + aa 
    return y
```

Or a class and do the same `setattr` trick

```
class D:
    pass
def myfuction(**kwargs):
    d = D()
    for k,v in kwargs.items():
        setattr(d,k,v)
    aa = d.b/2
    y = d.a + d.b + d.c + aa 
    return y

# OR put the attribute part in the class
class D:
    def __init__(self,dictionary):
        for k,v in dictionary.items():
            setattr(self,k,v)
def myfuction(**kwargs):
    d = D(kwargs)
    aa = d.b/2
    y = d.a + d.b + d.c + aa 
    return y
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is confusing because it isn't correct code. You need to get the value from the dictionary.

```
def myfunction(d1, d2)
    aa = d1['b'] / 2
    y = d1['a'] + d1['b'] + d2['c'] + aa
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, this is the problem you are facing.
I have a sample function to demonstrate this.

```
>>> def f(**kw):
...   print(kw)
```

You can't pass the same kwarg twice.

```
>>> f(a=10, b=20, a=30)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated
```

You can't do it by unpacking if the unpacked dicts have common keys.

```
>>> d1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> d2 = {'b': 3, 'c': 4}
>>> f(**d1, **d2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: f() got multiple values for keyword argument 'b'
```

---

However, you can create a new dict and unpack that instead to pass to the function.

```
>>> f(**{**d1, **d2})
{'a': 1, 'b': 3, 'c': 4}
```

You can do it without using `**kwargs` as well.

```
>>> def g(a, b, c):
...   print(f'{a=}, {b=}, {c=}')
... 
>>> g(**{**d1, **d2})
a=1, b=3, c=4
```